# Getting dates that exist in one table but not the other table using MYSQL and VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date, compare

I know there are many answers to this very question on the forum, but I simply cannot figure out what I am doing incorrect.  I've tried many methods and some got me close but not all the way there.

I have two tables:

'Attendance' with three fields 'ID, DLNumber, Time'

'Calendar' with 2 fields 'ID, Time'

[WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCgzX.png)

I am trying to find the dates that exist in the calendar table that DO NOT exist in the attendance table.

I need to search attendance between two dates and what matches a Driver's License Number. And then compare the results of that query to the dates in the calendar.

I have tried:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT calendar.Time FROM calendar WHERE 
calendar.Time NOT IN (SELECT attendance.Time FROM attendance WHERE 
attendance.DLNumber=?DL AND attendance.Time>= ?ST And 
attendance.Time < ?ET)"
```

When I run this query, I search between two dates 2023-10-23 and 2023-10-27, the results are
are all four dates back, where I need '2023-10-24' as the result.
No luck.

I've tried:

```
Dim sql As String = "Select calendar.Time,attendance.Time From calendar " _
& "Left Join attendance On attendance.time = calendar.Time WHERE 
attendance.DLNumber=?DL AND attendance.Time>= ?ST And 
attendance.Time < ?ET  Order BY calendar.Time"
```

Same results.

I'm sure I'm not explaining this correctly, so please forgive me for my MYSQL ignorance, I'm new to this.

Ok, so this gets me all the dates that macth in a chosen timeframe:

Ok...so this gets me all the dates that match from one table to another in the chosen time frame:

```
 Select calendar.Date,attendance.Date From calendar 
Left Join attendance On attendance.Date = calendar.Date WHERE 
attendance.DLNumber=?DL AND attendance.Date> ?ST And 
attendance.Date <=?ET AND  calendar.Date> ?ST And 
calendar.Date <= ?ET Order BY calendar.Date
```

How to I get the dates that DON'T match in a given timeframe?

So pretty much get all dates from 10-23-23 to 10-30-23 from BOTH tables, and compare them to get what dates are missing from the attendance table that are NOT missing from the calendar table...

Comment: When you do `LEFT JOIN` with a `WHERE` any columns from the table on the right, you'll just turning it into a normal join. Try changing `WHERE` to `AND` as a continuation of the `ON` condition. So, instead of `On attendance.time = calendar.Time WHERE attendance.DLNumber=?DL ...`, do `On attendance.time = calendar.Time AND attendance.DLNumber=?DL ... `

Comment: By the way, what does `Time` column stores? You better show us the table structures for both tables and include some data sample for clarification. You can get table structure by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;`

Comment: Actually, your first attempt should work but that depends on what you column `Time` values are.

Comment: The time columns are actually datetime type columns…..

Comment: You can expect the query to work if both tables, are storing the values like `'2023-10-24 00:00:00'`, which might be true for `calendar` table but I doubt that `attendance` table is like that. You can try with this on your first query attempt, change `.. calendar.Time NOT IN (SELECT attendance.Time ..` to `.. DATE(calendar.Time) NOT IN (SELECT DATE(attendance.Time) ...` and see what happens.

Comment: `SELECT c.Time FROM calendar AS c LEFT JOIN attendance AS a ON c.Time = date(a.time) WHERE a.time IS NULL`  the assumption here is that the attendance records might include "time of day" but the calendar does not

Comment: They are both datetime types which include times…

Comment: Yes, datetime's are **capable** of holding "time of day" but by default when you insert just yyyy-mm-dd then the time is set to 00:00:00 . The date() function simply extracts the date part of the date or datetime. i.e. removing the possibility that attendances have times such as  08:30:27

Comment: Could you teach why the behavior of the condition is different between `WHERE` and `ON` because I noticed that `WHERE` clause ignores null comparison unlike `ON`?
@FanoFN

Comment: @AhmedKhairy `WHERE` is what you use to filter. See this fiddle tests .. it might help https://dbfiddle.uk/ecEFWoZv

Comment: Ok...so this gets me all the dates that match from one table to another in the chosen time frame:  Select calendar.Date,attendance.Date From calendar 
Left Join attendance On attendance.Date = calendar.Date WHERE 
attendance.DLNumber=?DL AND attendance.Date> ?ST And 
attendance.Date <=?ET AND  calendar.Date> ?ST And 
calendar.Date <= ?ET Order BY calendar.Date

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are not using `LEFT JOIN` correctly. And you did not provide any table structure nor sample data - in which you revealed that you actually have a `date` column. First, you must understand that a `LEFT JOIN` basically means "I want everything from the left table to return result conditionally or unconditionally and return any matches from the right table based on certain column or condition". That will happen as long as you place the condition for the table on the right strictly in `ON`. When you define any condition referring to the table on the right in `WHERE`, you're filtering whatever condition that is true from the table on the right and that cancels the `LEFT JOIN` functionality.

So, what you're doing here:

```
Select calendar.Date,attendance.Date From calendar 
Left Join attendance On attendance.Date = calendar.Date 
WHERE [[ attendance.DLNumber=?DL 
        AND attendance.Date> ?ST 
        And attendance.Date <=?ET ]] <--- these cancel the left join function
AND  calendar.Date> ?ST And calendar.Date <= ?ET Order BY calendar.Date
```

What you should do is this:

```
SELECT calendar.Date,attendance.Date 
  /* table on the left */       /* table on the right */
FROM    calendar     LEFT JOIN    attendance 
 ON attendance.Date = calendar.Date 
/* continue these conditions in ON */
 AND attendance.DLNumber=?DL 
        AND attendance.Date> ?ST 
        AND attendance.Date <=?ET

/* WHERE filter here should only be for calendar table if you want to maintain the left join function */
WHERE calendar.Date> ?ST AND calendar.Date <= ?ET ORDER BY calendar.Date
```

You should see a difference in the result with this.

Here's a fiddle example: https://dbfiddle.uk/K4ynr2ai